# Alternative Console Output Streams

Tags: c++, iostream, io-redirection, stdio

In C/C++ the standard output streams: `stdout`/`stderr`,`std::cout`/`std::cerr` print to the console (not to mention `clog`, `wcout`...). These can be independently redirected from the command line.

Is there a way to add an *alternative* output stream that:

1. Prints to the console like the standard streams;
2. Does not get redirected with either of the standard streams.

In particular, I am interested in having some console output that does not get logged by redirection.

If there are no standard ways, then platform dependent ways (Linux and Windows) will also be helpful.

Comment: No *standard* way, but there are platform dependent ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @BasileStarynkevitch suggestions, the same can be done on Windows replacing `"dev/tty"` with `"con"`.

For completeness here's a full program demonstrating non-redirectable calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


#ifndef DEVTTY
#define DEVTTY "con"    // on Windows
// #define DEVTTY "/dev/tty" // on Linux/MacOS
#endif

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   cout << "DEVTTY = " << DEVTTY << endl;
   printf("Print[f]ed to stdout.\n");
   fprintf(stdout, "Print[f]ed to stdout.\n");
   cout << "Printed to std::cout" << endl;

   fprintf(stderr, "Print[f]ed to stderr.\n");
   cerr << "Printed to std::cerr" << endl;

   {
      // C, stdio version
      FILE* fd = fopen(DEVTTY, "w");
      fprintf(fd, "Printed to \"%s\"\n", DEVTTY); // will not be redirected
      fclose(fd);
   }

   {
      // C++, fstream version
      std::ofstream ofs(DEVTTY);
      ofs << "Printed via std::ofstream to \"" << DEVTTY << "\"" << endl; // will not be redirected
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Redirecting both `stdout` and `stderr` as in `StreamRedirection.exe > out.txt 2>&1` gives:

In `out.txt`:

```
DEVTTY = con
Print[f]ed to stdout.
Print[f]ed to stdout.
Printed to std::cout
Print[f]ed to stderr.
Printed to std::cerr
```

and in the Console (on Windows):

```
Printed to "con"
Printed via std::ofstream to "con"
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux systems, you might open `/dev/tty` and write to it. See [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html). Read also [console(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console.4.html) and perhaps consider `/dev/console` (but I recommend `/dev/tty`)

AFAIK, the C++ standard does not define such an output stream.

See also (on Posix) [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) which would be my preference (since `/dev/tty` wont work if you have no controlling terminal).